# PFArrayResultBlock(parse) is causing an error while converting to swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I am using parse as my backend and having many errors while i'm converting to swift 2.0.
I am attaching pics of an error i'm getting and the place where that function is being used in my project.

[image]
[image]

Any advice or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that your completion block is

```
PFArrayResultBlock
```

While the query expects

```
PFQueryArrayResultBlock
```

The types are slightly different - one expects [PFObject]? the other [AnyObject]?

Comment: it used to work in Swift 1.2. Any suggestions how i should make the change?

Comment: just replace static func findCityLocality(localityName:String, completionBlock: PFQueryArrayResultBlock)

Comment: If I do that, how do I retrieve the data from the function? Earlier, I was getting data in result variable and assigning it to events. If i replace result, error with PFQueryArrayResultBlock, how do i achieve the same thing

Comment: yes, just  you will be getting PFObjects not AnyObject so you might need to refactor whatever is calling findCityLocality

Comment: I will give a shot and get back if I cannot solve it. Thank you for the words.