# ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock causing Xcode source editor to have limited functionality

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am attempting a query from Parse to get the object ids in an array and not have to hard code the ids. I attempt to use the following code:

```
var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
 ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
   (objectsArray : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

     var ObjectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]

     for i in 0..<ObjectIDs.count{
       self.ObjectIDsPublicArray.append(ObjectIDs[i].objectId)

       }

     })
```

But the code causes Xcode to state "Xcode encountered a problem. Source editor functionality is limited.Attempting to restore"

Anyone know why that code would cause that? Also any suggestions to fix?

Comment: besides the point but variableName  ObjectIDQuery is a big no-no - all variable names should start with lowercase

Answer (score 1):

you are on the right path but Parse doesn't use `[AnyObject]?` anymore in their new SDK so change to `[PFObject]?`

Example:

```
 let objectIdQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
 objectIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objectsArray : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
           {
               if let objects = objectsArray
               {
                   for one in objects
                  {
                         let objectID = one.objectID      //<--- objectID
                     // then append the objectID into your data structure
                  }
               } 
            }
       })
```

Comment: I update the code with the full block I was thinking of using. Where you added those comments is that where I place "append.(ObjectIDs[i].objectId)"?

Comment: yes sir, if you are using my code just append `objectID` into your array

Comment: let objectIdQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
        objectIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (objectsArray : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
           if error == nil
            {
                if let objects = objectsArray
                {
                    for one in objects
                    {
                        let objectID = one.objectID.append(ObjectIDs.objectId)      //<--- objectID
                        // then append the objectID into your data structure
                    }
                }
            }
        })

Comment: but received an error of "Value type of 'PFObject' has no member 'objectID'"

Comment: You cannot do that **one.objectID.append** it's not a data structure

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, basically parse updated their SDK

Just change

```
[AnyObject]? to [PFObject]?
```

Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759356/pfarrayresultblockparse-is-causing-an-error-while-converting-to-swift-2-0) I think
[PFArrayResultBlock(parse) is causing an error while converting to swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759356/pfarrayresultblockparse-is-causing-an-error-while-converting-to-swift-2-0)